# How to remove controls from embedded mapsengine iframe (google maps)

Tags: maps

Is there any way to remove big control window from embedded mapsengine iframe?

Lets say im embedding 640x480 iframe of mapsengine and 1/4 of the screen takes  mapsengine layer controls.

```
<iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/view?mid=z-CXoJOwaOdI.k77h0_UeoKiw" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have You found any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

### Super simple solution

Set the width at **517px** or smaller. The control panel will disappear ... on desktop. It will magically appear on mobile.

### Slightly More Complicated Solution

#### The CSS

```
<style>
#mapsengine-box-outer {overflow: hidden;}
#mapsengine-box-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:590px;
    height:590px;
    border:5px solid #998;
    border-radius:10px;
    }
#mapsengine {margin: -30px 0 0 -350px;}
</style>
```

#### The HTML

```
<div id="mapsengine-box-outer">
    <div id="mapsengine-box-inner">
        <iframe id="mapsengine" width="1285" height="630"
        src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=*******">
        </iframe>
     </div>
</div>
```

I put up a page about this (including a mobile solution) on my site [Maps Engine Manipulation – Removing iframe Controls (featureListPanel)](http://nicwinndesign.com/maps-engine-manipulation-removing-iframe-controls-featurelistpanel-part-1/) and here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/nictwistedfreak/pen/iFAaB) to play with.